# manipulate column fields for clean representation

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, scripting

Hi I have data in txt file in following format

```
TCP dmz 10.20.10.144:8080 inside 10.1.1.98:59217, idle 0:00:11, bytes 1295, flags UFRIO
TCP dmz 10.20.10.144:8082 inside 10.1.1.98:31949, idle 0:00:13, bytes 956, flags UfrIO
TCP dmz 10.20.10.144:8082 inside 10.1.1.97:60194, idle 0:00:16, bytes 645, flags UfrIO
```

I want to only extract

IP address and bytes field, so final result should be

```
10.20.10.144 10.1.1.98 1295
10.20.10.144 10.1.1.98 956
10.20.10.144 10.1.1.97 645
```

Also at the end i want to group by bytes (3rd column) by first field. to get :

```
10.20.10.144 2896
```

Any help ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider awk:

```
awk -F '[ ,]' '{sub(/:.+$/, "", $3); sub(/:.+$/, "", $5); print $3, $5, $11}' file
10.20.10.144 10.1.1.98 1295
10.20.10.144 10.1.1.98 956
10.20.10.144 10.1.1.97 645
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments below:

```
awk -F '[ ,]' '{sub(/:.+$/, "", $3); a[$3]+=$11} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
10.20.10.144 2896
```

Comment: group by bytes (3rd column) by first field. to get :

10.20.10.144 2896

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment

Comment: after first filtering I want to group by to summs up on $3 by first row

Answer (score 1):

You can use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with `re.findall()` :

```
>>> [re.findall(r'(?<= )[\d\.]+(?!:)',line) for line in open('your_filename','r')]
[['10.20.10.14', '10.1.1.9', '1295'], 
 ['10.20.10.14', '10.1.1.9', '956'], 
 ['10.20.10.14', '10.1.1.9', '645']]
```

the following pattern `r'(?<= )[\d\.]+(?!:)'` match any combination of digits with dot (`[\d\.]+`) that preceding with space and not following by `:` .

Answer (score 0):

Textbook Awk: split correctly into fields, print only some of the fields, do a bit of grouped arithmetic and print out totals at the end:

`awk -F'[ :,]' '{print $3, $6, $15; sum[$3]+=$15} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]}'`